# Reverse array list dynamically

Tags: excel

I have an array list in column A (starting in `A2`) using:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(MonthSpend,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($A$1,A1,MonthSpend),0)),""}`
```

Where `MonthSpend` is a named range from a table on a separate sheet.

I have copied the formula down to `A300`, but inserted blanks in a number of rows.

From the picture you will see that I have each month showing up only on every 6th row. The formula in `A8` is:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(MonthSpend,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($A$1:A2,MonthSpend),0)),"")}
```

and in `A3:A7` there is nothing).

I named this range in column A `MonthAcc`.

In column B (starting in `B2`), I tried using:

```
=IF(MonthAcc>10,INDEX(MonthAcc,COUNTA(MonthAcc)+ROW(MonthAcc)-ROW(),1),"")
```

to reverse this list.

This didn't work because the reversal function in `B2` references a row near the bottom of the `MonthAcc` list, which is blank.

I'm trying to get it so that in B2 (in the picture below) it would have `January 1, 2020` and then in `B8` it would have `December 1, 2019` and then in `B14` it would have `November 1, 2019` and so on.

The list `MonthSpend` is dynamic so can be totally different lengths.

How do I reverse my dates but keep it starting at the top and only every 6th row?

[image]

[image]

In the second picture you will see a column called `Month`. It uses the function `=IF(E3="","",DATE(YEAR(C3),MONTH(C3),1))` starting in `F3` and copied down the entire table. This is the named range `MonthSpend`. It is dynamic in that for a different project, you could have dates ranging from April 2017 to January 2020 etc. So the months that show up in the `Month` column, are what I want in my new reversed list, spaced 6 rows apart.

Comment: So the MonthSpend has the data you want but you want to start at the bottom of that list and put one line from MonthSpend every 6th row?

Comment: @ScottCraner I added some more information. Hopefully it is clearer now. MonthSpend does have the data but it is dynamic and won't always have the data that I want to the bottom of the column in the table.

Answer (score 0):

With the column `Week ending` you can use the following formula:

```
=IF((MOD(ROW()+4,6)=0),LOOKUP(2,1/(COUNTIF(C$1:$C1,$A$2:$A$25-DAY($A$2:$A$25)+1)=0),$A$2:$A$25-DAY($A$2:$A$25)+1),"")
```

It returns distinct dates from list converted to first day of month (you can also convert to other formats using the appropriate functions.) in reverse order every sixth row. Dates must be sorted in source column in ascending order. **BUT!** For empty cells it returns first day of XX century, so I enter that date manually to C2, if it bothers, it can be hidden

[image]